# Baseball related problem (balls and boxes)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random, balls-in-bins

Thanks in advance for any help!

So I am trying to figure out if the number of hits an inning of baseball is random, or if hits tend to come in bunches.  To do this, I'm just using a fairly small sample of 10 games, which was 89 innings.  Over the 89 innings, there were 74 total hits.

Here is a breakdown of number per inning (times occured):
0 (42)
1 (27)
2 (14)
3 (5)
4 (1)

How should I go about this? Would I find the expected number of "zero" innings and compare my 42 with that? Find the probability of obtaining 42 "zeros" if it was actually random?

Maybe this is a stars-and-bars problem.

Let me know if this is unclear.

Any advice would help! Thank you!

Comment: Is that 74 total baserunners for both teams in all the games, or just for one team? Also, do you know how many total at-bats there were? That number depends on how often baserunners are tagged out. The idea is to try to make a model of a random process by which batters become baserunners with some probability $p$, where $p$ is just the number of baserunners divided by the number of at-bats.

Comment: I'm just looking at one team. So my team had a total of 74 baserunners over the 89 innings I examined.  I want to see if when a team gets a baserunner(s), if they are more likely to have another baserunner that inning.  If you think of the 89 innings as 89 boxes, and you randomly throw 74 balls into these 89 boxes, what are the chances that 42 boxes don't have a ball? Or the chances that 20 boxes have 2 or more balls? And can I conclude that if you have one baserunner, you are more likely to have another? Does this make sense?

Comment: That is a good question (about the likelihood of having another baserunner) and an interesting model for answering it. Now I understand why this is tagged balls-in-bins, and why you thought about "stars and bars". I had started down a somewhat different path, but let me think for a while about how this model applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems reasonable to hypothesize that the number of baserunners in each
inning is not completely random. After all, the teams exercise strategy
to try to win, by arranging the batting order, choosing when to replace
the pitcher, and so forth, with the objective of scoring as many runs as
they can (which requires getting baserunners) and preventing the other
team from scoring runs.
It's also reasonable to test the hypothesis by comparing the actual numbers
of baserunners with the expected  numbers you would get if the
process of becoming a baserunner were random.

If you assume there had to be exactly $74$ baserunners in $89$ innings,
then randomly distributing $74$ balls to $89$ boxes, where
each ball has an equal likelihood to be in any box, seems like a
reasonable model.

The probability that a ball number $i$ will *not* be in box number $j$
then is $88/89$, and the probability that box $j$ will be empty is
$(88/89)^{74} \approx 0.4333684068.$

Let $I_{jk}$ be $1$ if there are $k$ balls in box $j$, $0$ otherwise.
Let $N_k$ be the number of boxes containing exactly $k$ balls.
Then
$$N_k = \sum_{1\leq j\leq n} I_{jk}.$$
Observing that $E[I_{jk}]$ is the probability of $k$ balls in box $j$, and
all boxes have an equal chance to contain $k$ balls.
So if we let $X_j$ be the number of balls in box $j$, then
$$E[N_k] = \sum_{1\leq j\leq n} E[I_{jk}] 
= \sum_{1\leq j\leq n} P[X_j = k]
= nP[X_1 = k].$$

Therefore the expected number of innings with no baserunners would be
$89 (88/89)^{74} \approx 38.5697882019.$
Compare to the observed value, $42$.

The number of balls in each box [is reasonably well approximated by a
Poisson distribution](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jfc/cs174/lecs/lec5/lec5.pdf)
when $m$ and $n$ are much larger than $k$
(which they are for all the numbers of interest in this problem):

$$ P[X_j = k] \approx \frac{1}{k!} \left( \frac mn \right)^k e^{-m/n}.$$

For $m=74$, $n=89$, and $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, we get

\begin{array}{crr}
k & P[X_1 = k] \quad & n P[X_1 = k]\quad\\
0 &0.4354128253 &38.7517414554\\
1 &0.3620286413 &32.2205490753\\
2 &0.1505062891 &13.3950597279\\
3 &0.0417133535 &3.7124884639\\
4 &0.0086707533 &0.7716970403\\
5 &0.0014418781 &0.1283271483\\
\end{array}

So most of the numbers agree pretty well with observations.

I considered a slightly different model of the problem. 
Rather than assume there were
$74$ "baserunner" events that each had to find an inning in which to
occur, I assume that each time a player goes to bat, he has some
probability $p$ of becoming a baserunner.
I would like to estimate the probability $p$ so that the expected number
of baserunners is $74$.

A simplified model says that the inning ends when three players
have failed to become baserunners. This assumes that the only way for
a player to be "out" is while they are batting, not while they are running.
This is slightly unrealistic (because players sometimes *do* get out
while running) and overcounts the number of at-bats in $89$ innings.
But this model says that $p \approx 0.2170087977$
and that the number of baserunners per inning has the following distribution:

\begin{array}{crr}
k & P[X_1 = k] \quad & n P[X_1 = k]\quad\\
0 &0.4800325059 &42.7228930293\\
1 &0.3125138309 &27.8137309458\\
2 &0.1356365014 &12.0716486216\\
3 &0.0490571901 &4.3660899218\\
4 &0.0159687628 &1.4212198866\\
5 &0.0048515068 &0.4317841063\\
\end{array}

These figures are almost eerily close to the observed values.

It might be interesting to try to improve the model by accounting
for the probability that an inning ends with fewer than three
at-bats because baserunners get "out".
There would then be fewer than $3\times 89$ at-bats but
the value of $p$ would be correspondingly greater.

Comment: Wow! Great answer. So looks like there probably isn't enough to conclude baserunners don't occur at random from my sample.  Crazy how close those numbers are the my observed numbers! Must mean you made a great model! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Random distribution of 74 balls into 89 boxes, by simulation:
$$\begin{array}{rr|rr}
=0 & 39 & \ge0 & 89 \\
=1 & 32 & \ge1 & 50 \\
=2 & 13 & \ge2 & 18 \\
=3 & 4 & \ge3 & 5 \\
=4 & 1 & \ge4 & 1
\end{array}$$
I'd say that settles it, but feel free to draw your own conclusion.